# Can I use the oAuth access_token to get the final segment in the web service URL?

Tags: webservices, oauth2, security-token

Kind of a weird question but I'm trying to get the web service URL. My SforceService() object in C# has the first part of the URL but the final segment of it I still need to get. I know I can query the the identity URL from my token JSON response to get the web service URL but I also noticed the final segment of the web service URL is the exact same as the first part of the access_token. E.g.

The web service URL I'm trying to get:

```
 https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/21.0/00D300000000mlx
```

The final segment "00D300000000mlx" is also the first 15 characters of my access_token - everything in the access_token before the '!'

```
"access_token": "00D300000000mlx!AQoAQLszu53SID43zS24o89_njfAX70k1WBWRCMmo6TRSdgIuzkbOX2iC5qPw3t4tY2hFI4ZPxlAYidnSXISFu5puPO.liXs"
```

So instead of doing an extra query using the identity URL, is it safe to parse out the beginning of my access_token and append that to complete my web service URL? And simply assume everything before the '!' character in the access_token will always be the final segment of my web service URL?

If not, is there a preferred way to get that final segment of the web service URL?

Comment: '00D300000000mlx' , is the ORG ID. every environment in SF is a org with ID,  If you work will multiple org environments that ID will be different.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed when I query the identity URL, the JSON response has:

"organization_id": "00D300000000mlxEAA",

Which is the same ID + 3 extra letters. The identity URL in token JSON response also has:

 "id": "https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D300000000mlxEAA/00530000000gKV8AAM",

Which contains the same org ID + the 3 extra letters at the end. Do you know why there are 3 extra characters at the end? Can I simply remove the final 3 characters and safely use that for the final segment of my web service URL?

Comment: Those 3 extra letters are checksum bits added to make that ID case insensitive. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BQGnIAO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **not** assume that the 15-character ID at the beginning will always exist in an access token. In fact, you should not assume the access token is anything other than a series of characters that represents your current session. The OAuth flow includes an identity URL (/id/org-id/user-id) in the "id" key of the JSON response.

```
{ "id": "https://login.salesforce.com/id/org-id/user-id", ...
  "access_token": "...", ...
}
```

Accessing this resource gives you the following information:

```
{ ...
  { "urls": 
    { "enterprise": "https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/{version}/<<org-id-is-here>>",
      ...
    }        
  },
  ...
}
```

You will need to string-replace `{version}` with the appropriate version you want to use (e.g. `44.0`). This method is forwards compatible with new versions of the API. Doing anything less than this is **asking** for a broken integration in the future.

This is the **only** supported method. Do not be tempted to "save a callout" by mashing together bits of a URL. Anecdotally, I worked at an org that did this once, and one day we decided to enable My Domain, and it broke a critical integration. Make no assumptions, use standard features.